# Java: How to check that 2 binary files are same?

Tags: java

What is the easiest way to check (in a unit test) whether binary files A and B are equal?

Comment: md5 or sh1 may work for that

Comment: Hi, if you have using linux OS, use the "md5sum" command. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM

Comment: Are third-party libraries fair game?  Guava has [`Files.equal`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/io/Files.html#equal(java.io.File,%20java.io.File)).  There's no real reason to bother with hashing if you don't have to; it can only be less efficient.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Yes. Please submit your comment as an answer (Guava's Files.equal) and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Are third-party libraries fair game? Guava has [`Files.equal(File, File)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/io/Files.html#equal-java.io.File-java.io.File-). There's no real reason to bother with hashing if you don't have to; it can only be less efficient.

Comment: That api has @Beta annotation.

Answer (score 7):

There's always just reading byte by byte from each file and comparing them as you go.  Md5 and Sha1 etc still have to read all the bytes so computing the hash is extra work that you don't have to do.

```
if (file1.length() != file2.length()) {
    return false;
}
    
 try( InputStream in1 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file1));
    InputStream in2 = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file2));
 ) {

      int value1, value2;
      do {
           //since we're buffered, read() isn't expensive
           value1 = in1.read();
           value2 = in2.read();
           if(value1 != value2) {
               return false;
           }
      } while(value1 >= 0);
     
 // since we already checked that the file sizes are equal 
 // if we're here we reached the end of both files without a mismatch
 return true;
}
```

Comment: That depends how many times you need to compare. If you have file A, and you need to compare many files (B1,...,Bn) to it, then it may be more efficient to compute a hash. This way you don't have to go over the entire bytes of A every time you test. You could put the hash in your unit test and check against it (just make sure to change the hash if your file changes).

Answer (score 4):

With assertBinaryEquals.

`public static void assertBinaryEquals(java.io.File expected,
                                          java.io.File actual)`

http://junit-addons.sourceforge.net/junitx/framework/FileAssert.html

Answer (score 4):

Read the files in (small) blocks and compare them:

```
static boolean binaryDiff(File a, File b) throws IOException {
    if(a.length() != b.length()){
        return false;
    }
    
    final int BLOCK_SIZE = 128;
    InputStream aStream = new FileInputStream(a);
    InputStream bStream = new FileInputStream(b);
    byte[] aBuffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
    byte[] bBuffer = new byte[BLOCK_SIZE];
    do {
        int aByteCount = aStream.read(aBuffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        bStream.read(bBuffer, 0, BLOCK_SIZE);
        if (!Arrays.equals(aBuffer, bBuffer)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    while(aByteCount < 0);
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to avoid dependencies you can do it using quite nicely with Files.readAllBytes and Assert.assertArrayEquals

```
Assert.assertArrayEquals("Binary files differ", 
    Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(expectedBinaryFile)), 
    Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(actualBinaryFile)));
```

Note: This will read the whole file so it might not be efficient with large files.

Answer (score 3):

**Since Java 12** you could also use the `Files.mismatch` method [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#mismatch(java.nio.file.Path,java.nio.file.Path)). It will return `-1L` if the files are the same.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do the same in a unit test too, so I used SHA1 hashes to do that, to spare the the calculation of the hashes I check if the files sizes are equal first. Here was my attempt:

```
public class SHA1Compare {
    private static final int CHUNK_SIZE = 4096;

    public void assertEqualsSHA1(String expectedPath, String actualPath) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        File expectedFile = new File(expectedPath);
        File actualFile = new File(actualPath);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedFile.length(), actualFile.length());
        try (FileInputStream fisExpected = new FileInputStream(actualFile);
                FileInputStream fisActual = new FileInputStream(expectedFile)) {
            Assert.assertEquals(makeMessageDigest(fisExpected), 
                    makeMessageDigest(fisActual));
        }
    }

    public String makeMessageDigest(InputStream is) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException {
        byte[] data = new byte[CHUNK_SIZE];
        MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        int bytesRead = 0;
        while(-1 != (bytesRead = is.read(data, 0, CHUNK_SIZE))) {
            md.update(data, 0, bytesRead);
        }
        return toHexString(md.digest());
    }

    private String toHexString(byte[] digest) {
        StringBuilder sha1HexString = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i = 0; i < digest.length; i++) {
            sha1HexString.append(String.format("%1$02x", Byte.valueOf(digest[i])));
        }
        return sha1HexString.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Calculating the hash is more computationally intense than just comparing the two files byte-by-byte.

Comment: @Charlie, That's right, calculating the hash would be more suitable if the expected hash was already computed once and stored in some variable for the test, so only computing the hash of the actual file is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Commons IO solution:

```java
boolean sameFileContent = FileUtils.contentEquals(file1, file2)
```

From documentation:

Compares the contents of two files to determine if they are equal or not.
Checks that

1. The two files are different lengths or,
2. If they point to the same file,
3. And then does a byte-by-byte comparison of the contents.

Reference:
https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html